# Only one NSManagedObject gets added at a time in a to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have worked with core data in the best with little or no difficulty. In this new project. Im trying to add photos to a single project. Now the project entity gets created and saved with no issues. The issues comes about when i try to multiple photos to the project. It only lets me add one at a time, if i try to add a new one, it rewrites (substitutes) the previous one i added. Ive been trying to figure it out and try different approaches (manually add it to a mutable set and set the new set). Below is my code for creating both the project, the photos and adding the photo to the project.

Any help would be appreciated.

In 'viewWillAppear':

```
self.project = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
\\ set certain attributes
```

In 'imageController: didFinishPickingMediaWIthInfo:' delegate method

```
NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    void(^completion)(void) = ^(void) {
        if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
        {
            UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

            [self addPhotoToProject:image];
        }
    };

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:completion];
```

And lastly, my custom 'addPhotoToProject:'

```
Photo *temp = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    temp.img = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    temp.date = [NSDate date];
    temp.project = self.project;
    [self.project addPhotosObject:temp];
```

At this point, i re-pull the list of photos for the project and update the collectionView i have to display them. Also, the project itself is not saved at these points, the user must press save.

Comment: I think you should not put `self.project = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];` in `viewWillAppear`. Because `viewWillAppear` will be called when you dismiss the `imagePicker`. That means you keep inserting `projects` when you open and close the `imagePicker`

Comment: I took your suggestion and i moved it to `viewDidLoad` and now i get a `-[OS_dispatch_queue managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1454a370` like as if the self.project never got created @EricQian

Comment: Using `self.project` getter method to create a new project at run-time

Comment: How would you do that? @EricQian I have actually never done that before

Comment: OK I will post another answer to explain this feature, I am pretty sure you used that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong, in my `viewWillDissappear` method, i had the `managedObjectContext` rolling back. Since the `imagePickerController` kept popping up causing the project to get deleted. Thanks to @EricQian for the idea to check about viewWillAppear that led me to this

Answer (score 0):

To create a new `project` during runtime:

```
-(NSManagedObject *)project 
{
    if(!_project) {
        _project = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }
    return _project;
}
```

Comment: I added the code and now im getting `SIGARBT` crash when i try to either set the `project` object for the new `photo`

Comment: What's the crash log?

Comment: `-[OS_dispatch_queue managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165a4e20' & `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OS_dispatch_queue managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165a4e20'` and its not always the same object like 'OS_dispatch_queue` in this one, in my experience, this means the object never gets created like before

Comment: I found out what was wrong, in my `viewWillDisappear`, the context would rollback destroying the project. But thanks to you, i had an idea of what to look for. Thanks!